# Java - jar with librairies included

Tags: java, jar

I am currently trying to make a Jar with all my libraries included.
What I have done.
I have created folders like this :

- `main` folder
- `class` (which contain all my classes)
- `ressources` (containing all my libraries : mongo, jedis...)
- `MANIFEST.MF`

My main class is named `process`.

My manifest is like this:

```
Main-Class: process

Class-Path: ressources\commons-pool-1.5.6.jar ressources\jedis-2.0.0.jar resources\mongo-2.6.3.jar class
```

I have generated the JAR with this command :

```
jar cvmf MANIFEST.MF process.jar class/*.class ressources/*.jar
```

My problem : When executing the JAR I have still the message

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: process
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using eclipse? If yes, it have an option in export to export libraries together with jar..

with netbeans, I dont know how to do it.

Comment: No I am using Netbeans. If I don't find how to manage that with Netbeans, maybe I will install Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

You could build your jar with Ant using zipfilesets to copy in the content of the other jars (rather than the jars themselves), or you could take a look at [jarjar](http://code.google.com/p/jarjar/) which does that and more.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse: You have to add the external jar files to the build.properties, otherwise they are no tpart of the generated jar file.

Ar the libraries included in the jar file, you have generated?

Comment: With Netbeans, I just have generated a JAR including the libraries (I check), but still the same message. Seems I have to change the MANIFEST...

Comment: ok, but try to unzip the generated jar file and check, whether the additional libraries are included

Comment: I checked, additional librairies are included

Comment: OK path of the additional librairies must be the same between Compile and Run. Now I have the message : "Failed to load Main-Class manifest attribute from". I continue to search...

Comment: OK now it works. In fact, in Netbeans, we have to create a java project as application, include libraries in src/lib. But now strange, if I copy my JAR generated on one place on a directory it can work and on another place it can not work...